# Strange android DEX Error

Tags: android, dex

I'm trying to compile my Android App and getting these weird errors (not warnings, actual errors)

```
Android Dex: [MyApp] (org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.DefaultErrorHandlingPolicies$1) that doesn't come with an
Android Dex: [MyApp] associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Android Dex: [MyApp] compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Android Dex: [MyApp] solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Android Dex: [MyApp] and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
```

Android Dex: [MyApp] trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class":
.....

I've been compiling this app for quite a while without trouble, but recently have made a lot of changes including introducing the support package and actionBarSherlock...

I can't find anything in my source code related to the error messages.

As far as I can tell, this error is suspect when importing JARs?

I'm using IntelliJ 12 to manage my dependencies (not Maven).

They are:

```
MyApp:
 - MyOtherModule
 - actionbarsherlock

MyOtherModule:
 - JUnit
 - commons-lang3-3.1
 - jetty-distribution-9.0.3
 - google-gson-2.2

actionbarsherlock:
 - android-support-v4.jar
```

All set to 'Compile'.

Unfortunately, it's kind of hard at this point to remove these libraries one-by-one to see what the problem is... has anyone else experienced this error with any of these JARs, or knows how to debug it?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Can you please put the actual error log?

Answer (score 0):

The problem library was Jetty - removing that import fixes it. I guess I need to use a different HttpClient as it seems it's not compatible with Android for some reason.